# Serilog .NET upgrade some log properties are gone

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, serilog, .net-core-3.1, serilog-aspnetcore

I upgraded .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6 and also include serilog. It is noticed that SpanId of log message is gone but I can see RequestId property. I would like to know what is happening behind the scene for this change since I am unable to find a proper changelog.

Here are my .NET 6 packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Process" Version="2.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Thread" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.AwsCloudWatch" Version="4.0.171" />
```

These are the .NET Core 3.1 packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="3.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Environment" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Process" Version="2.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Enrichers.Thread" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.AwsCloudWatch" Version="4.0.171" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing [Serilog.Enrichers.Span](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Enrichers.Span) and then adding `.Enrich.WithSpan()` to the logger setup:

```cs
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.WithSpan()
    ...  
    .CreateLogger();
```

Check out this [github comment](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/issues/207#issuecomment-668323842), it seems that `SpanId` became opt-in in .NET 5.